Is there a way to rename prefab in unity by cuting a specific part of the name?
I have a lot of old prefabs in unity that should get renamed, doing this by hand would take a while. I there a way to cut the names and save them. I would like it to go from cutpart_2_goodpart to goodpart so everything before goodpart (It would probably include separating string by _ but there are 2 of them)

Whichever method you are going to pick, be sure to test it first on a selected few to make sure that the references of the prefabs are not breaking. Else you will have a bigger problem than a bad name

Have you looked at writing a script that uses AssetDatabase.RenameAsset? This will change the file name (including .meta file name) without breaking GUID references, as Zibelas cautions about, and will return an error message if this cannot be done due to a naming conflict/file permissions/etc.

No didn't know this existed tnx, I will take a look
